# functor call (additional characters)

Tags: c++, call, functor

I tried to build a minimal example:

```
struct Functor
{
    void operator()(int& a)
    {
        a += 1;
    }
    void other(int& a)
    {
        a += 2;
    }
};

template <typename foo>
class Class
{
    public:
        void function()
        {
            int a = 10;
            foo()(a);
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Class<Functor> c;
    c.function();
}
```

My question about this: Why is it even possible to call the operator on the pure type without an object? How can I call the function `other` the same way as I call `operator()`?

Comment: Where's the "pure type"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not calling it on a pure type.  `foo()` invokes the constructor, and evaluates to a temporary `foo` object, on which you then invoke `operator()`.

To do the equivalent with a "normal" member function, just do:

```
foo().other(a);
```

Comment: That means for every call there will be an object allocated on the stack?

Comment: @DyingSoul: If you do it like this, then yes!  Although the compiler is free to optimise that however it likes.

Comment: @DyingSoul: yes and no, since your structure is empty, and since the methods are inline, it is likely that the compiler will simply execute the code within the method "in place" (equivalent to replacing `foo()(a)` with `a += 1`. If your method is not inline (for whatever reason), then it will have to reserve a byte (at least) on the stack, because a valid address needs to be passed to the method (the `this`) and it cannot know you do not need it, in fact.

Answer (score 3):

You are not *"call[ing] the operator on the pure type without an object"*. The syntax `foo()(a)` is creating a temporary of type `foo` (this is the `foo()` part) and then calling `operator()` on that object with `a` as argument: (the `(a)` part).

Answer (score 2):

Pure type example:

```
struct Functor
{
    void operator()(int& a)
    {
        a += 1;
    }
    void other(int& a)
    {
        a += 2;
    }
    static void one_more(int& a)
    {
        a += 3;
    }
};

template <typename foo>
class Class
{
    public:
        void function()
        {
            int a = 10;
            foo()(a);
            foo().other(a);
            foo::one_more(a);
            std::cout << a << std::endl;
        }
};

int main()
{
    Class<Functor> c;
    c.function();
}
```

Comment: To call the static function is more efficient because we dont need to create an instance on the stack, right?

Comment: And the compiler can inline the static funtion because it will be resolved at compile time?

Comment: @DyingSoul: In this scenario, all three will probably be turned into identical machine code.  The constructor has no observable side effects, so the compiler can optimise it away entirely.